GCC 13.02 fail during Yocto build for Nanbield version 4.3.4
I am building Yocto Linux image for Intel Atom X6211E processor based Congatec TCA7 board but during build process I am getting GCC 13.02 do-compile error on my system. Yocto distro version is nanbield 4.3.4.
This is small clip of errors.
Error Log-----
/home/synergy/DCU/poky/build/tmp/work/corei7-64-poky-linux/gcc/13.2.0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/x86_64-poky-linux/../../libexec/x86_64-poky-linux/gcc/x86_64-poky-linux/13.2.0/ld: insn-recog.o: in function `split_insns(rtx_def*, rtx_insn*)':
/usr/src/debug/gcc/13.2.0-r0/gcc/config/i386/sse.md:2170:(.text+0x1cd0df): undefined reference to `gen_split_845(rtx_insn*, rtx_def**)'
/home/synergy/DCU/poky/build/tmp/work/corei7-64-poky-linux/gcc/13.2.0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/x86_64-poky-linux/../../libexec/x86_64-poky-linux/gcc/x86_64-poky-linux/13.2.0/ld: insn-recog.o: in function `peephole2_insns(rtx_def*, rtx_insn*, int*)':
/usr/src/debug/gcc/13.2.0-r0/gcc/config/i386/i386.md:21789:(.text+0x1cd440): undefined reference to `gen_peephole2_118(rtx_insn*, rtx_def**)'
/home/synergy/DCU/poky/build/tmp/work/corei7-64-poky-linux/gcc/13.2.0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/x86_64-poky-linux/../../libexec/x86_64-poky-linux/gcc/x86_64-poky-linux/13.2.0/ld: /usr/src/debug/gcc/13.2.0-r0/gcc/config/i386/i386.md:1307:(.text+0x1cd71d): undefined reference to `gen_peephole2_276(rtx_insn*, rtx_def**)'
/home/synergy/DCU/poky/build/tmp/work/corei7-64-poky-linux/gcc/13.2.0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/x86_64-poky-linux/../../libexec/x86_64-poky-linux/gcc/x86_64-poky-linux/13.2.0/ld: /usr/src/debug/gcc/13.2.0-r0/gcc/config/i386/i386.md:1317:(.text+0x1cd937): undefined reference to `gen_peephole2_305(rtx_insn*, rtx_def**)'
/home/synergy/DCU/poky/build/tmp/work/corei7-64-poky-linux/gcc/13.2.0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/x86_64-poky-linux/../../libexec/x86_64-poky-linux/gcc/x86_64-poky-linux/13.2.0/ld: /usr/src/debug/gcc/13.2.0-r0/gcc/config/i386/i386.md:1307:(.text+0x1cdb30): undefined reference to `gen_peephole2_274(rtx_insn*, rtx_def**)'
/home/synergy/DCU/poky/build/tmp/work/corei7-64-poky-linux/gcc/13.2.0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/x86_64-poky-linux/../../libexec/x86_64-poky-linux/gcc/x86_64-poky-linux/13.2.0/ld: /usr/src/debug/gcc/13.2.0-r0/gcc/config/i386/i386.md:1317:(.text+0x1ce163): undefined reference to `gen_peephole2_302(rtx_insn*, rtx_def**)'
/home/synergy/DCU/poky/build/tmp/work/corei7-64-poky-linux/gcc/13.2.0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/x86_64-poky-linux/../../libexec/x86_64-poky-linux/gcc/x86_64-poky-linux/13.2.0/ld: /usr/src/debug/gcc/13.2.0-r0/gcc/config/i386/i386.md:21757:(.text+0x1ce594): undefined reference to `gen_peephole2_117(rtx_insn*, rtx_def**)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [../../../../../../../work-shared/gcc-13.2.0-r0/gcc-13.2.0/gcc/lto/Make-lang.in:96: lto1] Error 1
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make[1]: *** [../../../../../../../work-shared/gcc-13.2.0-r0/gcc-13.2.0/gcc/lto/Make-lang.in:102: lto-dump] Error 1
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [../../../../../../../work-shared/gcc-13.2.0-r0/gcc-13.2.0/gcc/c/Make-lang.in:87: cc1] Error 1
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [../../../../../../../work-shared/gcc-13.2.0-r0/gcc-13.2.0/gcc/cp/Make-lang.in:145: cc1plus] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/synergy/DCU/poky/build/tmp/work/corei7-64-poky-linux/gcc/13.2.0/gcc-13.2.0/build.x86_64-poky-linux.x86_64-poky-linux/gcc'
make: *** [Makefile:4627: all-gcc] Error 2
ERROR: oe_runmake failed
WARNING: exit code 1 from a shell command.


Kindly suggest any solution for that.
